# MapView в Yandex mapkit, Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, yandexmapkit, mapview

После вроде бы успешной привязки библиотеки к проекту, возникла сложность в обращении к классу MapView, в документации яндекса, пакет com.yandex.mapkit.mapview есть, а в проекте xamarin.android после привязки его нету. Для отображения карты к нему необходимо обратиться, и я не пойму понимаю как, раз его нету?!  Если есть знатоки, подскажите. Или есть иной способ отобразить карту яндекса?

```
<Com.Yandex.Mapkit.Mapview.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="тут мой ключ"
    android:tag="static"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

MainActivity

```
 using Com.Yandex.Mapkit.Mapview.MapView; public class YandexMapActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var map = FindViewById<MapView>(Resource.Id.map);

    }
}
```

Comment: [На данный момент Xamarin приложения не поддерживаются.](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/faq-docpage/)

Comment: Поддержка яндекса также ответила, что библиотека не поддерживает интерфейс для C# и ответила что  нужно писать вручную биндинги для использования.

Comment: У кого какие предложения? Смириться и не использовать вовсе яндекс карты в моем проекте и не теряя время разбираться в google картах, или все же есть решение? P.S яндекс карты больше детализацией нравятся и приоритет больше на них))

Comment: Никто же кроме вас здесь не знает ваш бэкграунд, потому что-либо советовать... Если рискнете писать биндинги, то создавайте публичный репозиторий на гитхабе и дайте знать, авось подсоблю чем-нибудь.

Comment: Реализовать Activity (Fragment) с картой нативно для каждой платформы

Comment: Получилось сделать?